# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - .Net Core 1.0.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

**Update**: Even a new .net core web application is showing the same error.

I'm using .Net Core Version 1.0.0-preview2-003131.

I upgraded a .Net Core SDK from Version 1.0.0-preview2-003121 to the above mentioned. Now when I try to run the application I get the error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image]

When I searched on Internet most of the stuff is to change the Port number. I change that and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas how to fix this?

The project.json file is:

```
   {
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-Angle_MVC6_jQuery-f82e2f9a-a8b7-4a73-83f2-8e1da291a076",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.4.337",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

My Debug configuration is as 
[image]

And the Solution Explorer window is
[image]

Comment: Hi, are you using VS 2017 ?

Comment: no i'm using VS professional 2015

Comment: I faced the similar issue but most of the persons are recommended VS 2017. bug : https://forums.asp.net/p/2116754/6121801.aspx?Re+Redirect+page+is+not+working+in+Unauthorized+Access+401+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that this happens when we are missing the following under the `dependencies` in `project.json`

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    }
```

**NOTE** If the version is wrong (in the above mentioned) then also we see the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I personally stumbled onto a similar issue when I updated my app to Microsoft.NETCore.App: 1.1.1

In my case it throws a bunch of warnings at run-time with warnings about "element 'xxx' in namespace 'http//schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element...

For the time being rolling back to Microsoft.NETCore.App: 1.1.0 will do.

[Some Info that I found related to the issue](http://howstevegotburnedtoday.com/2007/04/10/visual-studio-warning-the-element-xxxx-in-namespace-httpschemas-microsoft-comdevelopermsbuild2003-has-invalid-child-element-yyyy-in-namespace-httpschemas-microsoft-comdevelope/)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `MyWebApplication\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` verify if the `bindingInformation` **PORT** is the same port in `Right click on your project > Debug > App URL`

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. Upgraded from Core 1.1.0 to 1.1.1 in simple pet project - can't run\debug on IIS Express. Looks like Core 1.1.1 build isn't stable enough.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have enable https in binding and add a developer certificate then it works like a charm.