# Attempts of migrate from net core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, migration

Good Morning
I'm migrating from 2.2 to 3.0 and then moving to 3.1 in net core with visual studio 2019
**my first attempt** was the most basic:

[docs of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Although it is a reduced version, I add it to my code leaving the packages that I still have to use for my project and it does not work ... **result: 404**

**second try:**

[err_connection_refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684336/err-connection-refused-net-core-1-0-1)

change the ip project of both http and https in addition to comparing it with the .json
**result: 404 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

**third try:**
[migrate 2.2 to 3.0 stackoverlofw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114413/how-do-i-migrate-net-core-2-2-web-api-to-net-core-3-0)

reduce it as much as possible but without success too

**the fourth attempt** was the most "*promising*"

https://github.com/StackExchangeExamples/DotNetCoreTargetDotNetFramework/tree/master/BasicCoreWebsite

since it showed a "complete" example of how a project with version 3.0 should look

the result: a page that says "hello world" instead of a 404, is not something successful but better than a 404 is not it?

***The idea of ​​this post is not only to solve my situation so that I do not get kicked out (lol) but to create as much as possible a complete functional example for future people with the same problem.***

Thank you very much in advance and the data you require I will upload with pleasure!

UPDATE (i add the startup.cs)

```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using HistoriaClinica.IServicio;
using HistoriaClinica.IServicio.Servicio;
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

namespace HistoriaClinica
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        /// <summary>
        ///  This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services"></param>
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            //services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();

            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            });

            services.AddDataProtection().UseCryptographicAlgorithms(
                new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
                {
                    EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
                    ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
                });

           // services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);


            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
                options.EnableForHttps = true;
                options.MimeTypes = new[]
                {
                    // General
                    "text/plain",
                    // Static files
                    "text/css",
                    "application/javascript",
                    // MVC
                    "text/html",
                    "text/xml",
                    "application/json",
                    "text/json",
                    "image/png",
                    "image/jpeg",
                    "image/svg+xml",
                    "application/octet-stream",
                    "application/font-woff",
                    "application/pdf"
                };
            });

            services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
                options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal
                );

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddSingleton<ILoggerServicio, LoggerServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<IEncriptaServicio, EncriptaServicio>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpServicio, HttpServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<IPacienteServicio, PacienteServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<IProfesionalServicio, ProfesionalServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<IEspecialidadServicio, EspecialidadServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<ILaboratorioServicio, LaboratorioServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<IUsuarioServicio, UsuarioServicio>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<ISessionServicio, SessionServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<IImagenServicio, ImagenServicio>();          
            services.AddScoped<INoticiaServicio, NoticiaServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<IResponseServicio, ResponseServicio>();
            services.AddScoped<IClienteServicio, ClienteServicio>();

           // services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            // Cron jobs
            //services.AddCronJob<RecordatorioTurno24>(c =>
            //{
            //    c.TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
            //    c.CronExpression = @"*/1 * * * *";
            //});
            //services.AddCronJob<RecordatorioTurno48>(c =>
            //{
            //    c.TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
            //    c.CronExpression = @"* * * * *";
            //});

            services.AddRazorPages();

        }
```

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

```
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseSession();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Cuenta/Error");
        }
        
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller=Cuenta}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

        });
     
        //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        //{
        //    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        //        name: "default",
        //        pattern: "{controller=Cuenta}/{action=Login}");
        //});

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your first project's startup?

Comment: Hi @luis,What is your main problem?

Comment: the only way i solve it is adding "lunchurl" in appsetting.json (in docs dosnt mention nothing about that line)